# Programmatically registering a performance counter in the registry

Tags: windows, registry, performancecounter

I'm trying to register a performance counter and part of this process includes adding some textual descriptions to a specific registry key.  For English this key is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\009 which apparently is also known as HKEY_PERFORMANCE_TEXT.  There are a pair of values under there (Counter, Help) that have REG_MULTI_SZ data, and I need to modify them to accomplish my goal.

The official way of doing this is by using a [tool called lodctr along with a .h and .ini file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371878%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  There is also a [function for doing this programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372187%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), but my understanding is that it is just a simple wrapper around calling the lodctr program.  I found the prospect of maintaining, distributing, and keeping synchronized 3 separate files a bit cumbersome, so I previously wrote code to do this and it worked fine under Windows XP (and possibly Vista, though I don't remember for sure).

Now I'm trying to use the same code on Windows 7 and it doesn't work.  The problem is that whenever I try to set the registry values it fails with ERROR_BADKEY; even regedit fails to modify the values, so it's not a problem with my code.  I ran Process Monitor against it and noticed that there was no activity at the driver level, so it seems this access must be getting blocked in user-mode code (e.g. advapi32.dll or wherever).  I understand why Microsoft would try to prevent people from doing this as it is very easy to screw up, and doing so will screw up the entire performance counter collection on the machine.

I'm going to debug lodctr and see what the magic is purely out of curiosity, but I'm wondering if anybody has run into this before?  Are there any alternatives other than the lodctr utility?  Perhaps calling the NT registry API directly?  I would really prefer to avoid the hassle of the lodctr method if possible.

A minimal example to reproduce the issue:

```
HKEY hKey = NULL;
LONG nResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Perflib\\009"), 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);
if(ERROR_SUCCESS == nResult)
{
    LPCTSTR lpData = _T("bar");
    DWORD cbData = (_tcsclen(lpData) + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR);
    nResult = RegSetValueEx(hKey, _T("foo"), 0, REG_SZ, (const BYTE*)lpData, cbData);
    // here nResult == ERROR_BADKEY
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
    hKey = NULL;
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

I spent about an hour or so trying to debug the official APIs and couldn't figure it out so I tried some more Google.  After a while I came across [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933241) which explains the RegSetValueEx behavior.  Since it mentioned modifying system files that got me to thinking that perhaps this particular registry data is backed by a mapped file.  Then I came across [another KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300956) that mentions Perfc009.dat and Perfh009.dat in the system32 folder.  Opened these up in a hex editor and sure enough it is the raw REG_MULTI_SZ data I am trying to modify.  Now that I know that maybe I can take another look and figure it out, though I am bored with it for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I give up.  It's easier to just go with the flow.  Instead of trying to modify the registry directly, I will create the .h and .ini files programmatically and invoke the relevant functions.