# Performance Counters in c++ without lodctr

Tags: c++, windows, performancecounter

I'm kind of used to the way how C# applications are able to create performance counters - just instantiating new `PerformanceCounter` object, and using it.

I'm now forced to use unmanaged C (C++?), and I'm really unhappy with ease of use of the API and samples provided. My main pain is the need to use lodctr for loading manifest, [as is told in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965334%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I wasn't able to find any solution for this. Is there any way how can I use Performance counters without having explicitly loading the manifest, as I can do in C#?

Comment: [I've been down a similar road](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532767/programmatically-registering-a-performance-counter-in-the-registry).  As far as I can tell there is no alternative to using lodctr.

Comment: Take a look at [LoadPerfCounterTextStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372187(v=vs.85).aspx). Don't sure if it is exactly what you need, but it may be a good start.

Comment: Interestingly, the Lodctr route is now the approach with C# apps too, if you're using the new CounterSet API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancedata(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the PDH (Performance Data handler) library.
The basic flow goes like this

```
// During startup call
h = PdhOpenQuery()
for each counter
   PdhAddCounter( h ... )

// When you want the data values call
PdhCollectQueryData( h )
for each counter
   PdhGetFormattedCounterValue()
```

Comment: I've found only some examples how to use PDH for reading the counters, `PdhAddCounter` serves for adding already existing counter to query. Is there any method how can I create my perf counters?

Comment: I have never made new performance counters, only accessed existing ones.